# How to circumvent this incredibly annoying Android AutoCompleteTextView bug

Tags: android

I am using AutoCompleteTextView (ACTV) in my app.

The `ACTV` is vertically positioned around `100px` from the top.

When user clicks on it, software keyboard opens and the suggestions dropdown appears *below* the ACTV.

Now I am getting to the bug - when user taps on some suggestion from the dropdown, the dropdown jumps *above* the ACTV!

So if I want to select a suggestion, I have to tap on the screen twice - firstly when the dropdown is below and then after it jumps to the top (by "jumps" I mean it immediately disappears under my finger and opens above).

Any idea how to circumvent this bug?

Comment: I would suggest deploying the app to an actual device to see if you can repeat the bug, and out of curiousity do you use LogCat at all?

Comment: I was testing it on the Droid. In emulator this bug appears only with 854px screen height and not with 480px height. LogCat doesn't say anything when this happens.

Comment: have you tried using flags or the advanced apis with your IME? (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html)